# How to use Custom Dependency Properties directly in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

**Edit**: I changed the code according to Thorstens Answer, using the enum, but did not work.

I am using Dependency Properties to influence a WPF control I am creating. I'm new to WPF, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and I can't find proper articles explaining it.

For example, I'm trying to define the Visibility of a control via Dep Properties. The property, in this case, would be this:

```cpp
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconVisibilityBoldProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("IconVisibilityBold", typeof(Visibility), typeof(RTFBox),
new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden), VisibilityValidateCallback);
private static bool VisibilityValidateCallback(object value)
{
 Visibility prop = (Visibility) value;
 if (prop == Visibility.Hidden || prop == Visibility.Visible)
 {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
public Visibility IconVisibilityBold
{
 get
 {
  return (Visibility)GetValue(IconVisibilityBoldProperty);
 }
 set
 {
  SetValue(IconVisibilityBoldProperty, value);
 }
}
```

**Edit:** for correct XAML, look for Slugarts answer.
The XAML Entry for this, in this case a ToggleButton, would be

```
<ToggleButton Visibility="{Binding Path=IconVisibilityBold}" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never" x:Name="ToolStripButtonBold" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" ToolTip="Bold">
<Image Source="Images\Bold.png" Stretch="None"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

I've output the Property, it shows as "Hidden" as the Metadata Default Value should imply, but apparently I've done something wrong with the binding. What would I have to write there?

Comment: Are you creating a new custom or user control?  Or are you just changing the data template of ToggleButton?  In which class is your property defined?

Comment: I just want to hide the button according to the property value, the properties are defined in the same class the buttons and other controls are located. (In this case named "RTFBox"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to binding to a property of the parent control without referencing it, and it won't be set implicitly.  You need to set the ElementName in the ToggleButton binding to be the name of the UserControl you are creating (giving it an x:Name property if it doesn't have one already).

```
<UserControl x:Name="rtfBox">
<ToggleButton Visibility="{Binding ElementName=rtfBox, Path=IconVisibilityBold}" ... />
...
</UserControl>
```

Also you should follow the previous answers which correctly state that the Visibility property is an enum and not a string.

Comment: So I assume you mean something like _<ToggleButton x:Name="BoldButton"_?
How would I have to reference the parent control in the binding?

Answer (score 1):

So your property is a string...but it has to be a enumerable:

```
namespace System.Windows
{
    public enum Visibility : byte
    {
        Visible,
        Hidden,
        Collapsed,
    }
}
```

You have to bind textbox the datacontext or use it as reference to access the property correctly

Comment: Whoops, accidentially wrote my answer as a comment :-) So you beat me to it.

Comment: I've changed the property thus:
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconVisibilityBoldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconVisibilityBold", typeof(Visibility), typeof(RTFBox), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));

but it still doesn't seem to work correctly (setters, getters and variable changed accordingly)

Comment: I can't return the Property itself, as it's of type "DependencyProperty", I have to use GetValue, and GetValue returns tpye object, so I have to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToggleButton`'s `Visibility` property requires a value of type `System.Windows.Visibility`. You need to change your code to use that instead of strings:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconVisibilityBoldProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("IconVisibilityBold", typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), typeof(RTFBox));

public System.Windows.Visibility IconVisibilityBold
{
 get
 {
  return (System.Windows.Visibility)GetValue(IconVisibilityBoldProperty);
 }
 set
 {
  SetValue(IconVisibilityBoldProperty, value);
 }
}
```